# Missing the Health.app on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app

I lost icon for the Health.app (the one with the Heart icon) on my iPhone. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Setings > General > Restrictions and enable it.

Do nothing and re-enable it, the app should be back. On iOS 10 and later, you might also need to go to the App Store and reinstall system apps so be sure to try that as well.

Last - look for any profiles in settings in case someone managing your device has prevented use of that app systematically. You can generally remove the profile or ask them to reassign your device if you should have access to the health app and store health data on your device.

Comment: How to enable “system apps” from the App Store?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to choose settings was correct for iOS 9 and earlier.

On iOS 10 you could have deleted the app and need to re-download it from the App Store.

Also - if you have a provisioning profile that disables that app by policy, you would have to remove that restriction or get the administrator that supervised your iOS device to remove that restriction.